# angular-ui modal with controller as syntax

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular-ui-bootstrap-bower#0.7.0 with angular#1.2.10 and when opening a modal where the controller is an "old fashioned" one, everything works fine.

However, when I have a controller meant to use with the new "controller as syntax" it doesn't work. Does [angular-ui-bootstrap modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) work with [controller as syntax](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.se/2013/11/ControllerAsSyntaxInAngularJs1.2.html)? Does version 0.7 support it? How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried to do when you say that it doesn't work? You need to show us your code or even better create a sample plunker

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the ngController syntax for the "controller" option.
For example:

```
controller: 'modalController as modal'
```

There is a [sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LezZNZ?p=preview)

Code from plunker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="demoController as demo">
    <h1>{{ demo.message }}</h1>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="demo.modal()">Open modal</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal window</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <pre>{{ modal.modalText }}</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="modal.cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('demoController', function($modal) {
  this.message = 'It works!'
  this.modal = function() {
    $modal.open({
      controller: 'modalController as modal',
      templateUrl: 'modal.html'
    });
  };
})
.controller('modalController', function($modalInstance) {
  this.modalText = 'Modal Text'
  this.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
  }
})
```

Comment: is this the only way to accomplish this? I like to inline my Controllers and *not* register them on the module with module.controller... so this won't work

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using CoffeeScript, don't forget to explicitly `return` the controller function.

Otherwise, the last line will be returned and you will end up with a not working `controller as` syntax, and incidentally, on this SO page.

Answer (score 0):

Set `'controllerAs'` property in `$uibModal.open()`

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation:true,
    templateUrl: '_myModal.html',
    controller:['$scope' function($scope){
    var mdCtrl=this;
    mdCtrl.title="hello world";
    }],
    controllerAs:'mdCtrl', //set your custom controllerAs name
    backdrop: 'static',
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {
    }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    }, function () {
    });
```

in your template

```
    <h2> {{mdCtrl.title}}</h2>
```